# Find an invertible matrix B such that BAB^-1 takes a specific form

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is to find an invertible matrix $B$ such that $B^{-1}AB$ making $A$ becomes
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & * &*  &* \\ 
-b & a &* &*  &* \\ 
 0& 0 &  *&*  &* \\ 
\vdots & \vdots &*  &*  &* \\ 
0 & 0 &  *&  *& *
\end{pmatrix}

How to write the proof formally? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "such that $B^{-1}AB$ making $A$ becomes"?

Comment: I think the question is asked to prove the existence of B.

Comment: You may want to add that $A$ is a square matrix with real entries. Then $B$ is any invertible matrix that has as its first two columns the real and imaginary part of any eigenvector of a complex eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compute the basis for the complex Jordan normal form and then replace each conjugate complex pair of generalized eigenvectors by their real and imaginary parts. This now real basis assembled into a matrix B keeping the previous order of generalized eigenvectors gives the desired transformation.

---

Since you are only concerned with the first two columns, you can take for $B$ any invertible matrix that has as its first two columns the real and imaginary parts of the eigenvector for any complex, i.e., non-real, eigenvalue. If the eigenvalue is $\lambda=a+ib$ and the eigenvector is $v=x+iy$, then from

$$A(x+iy)=(a+ib)(x+iy)=(ax-by)+i(ay+bx)$$

it follows that

$$A[x,y]=[x,y]\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{bmatrix}$$

Extending $[x,y]$ by additional columns to a square invertible matrix gives a candidate for $B$.

---

See also real Schur normal form.

Comment: Can you say something more how to prove the existence of B?

Comment: It is the direct consequence of the existence of the Jordan normal form.

Comment: Thanks LutxL for your explanation. I get what you mean that the first column is the real parts of the and the second column is the imaginary parts of the eigenvector.

Comment: if we haven't learnt Jordan form, can we proceed by elementary linear algebra like row operations?

Comment: If you just proceed one eigenvector at a time, reducing the matrix under consideration to the lower left submatrix after each step, then you do not need the Jordan normal form and end up with the real form of the Smith normal form, which is also the result of the QR-algorithm for the numerical determination of the eigenvalues.

Comment: I see it. Thank you so much.